# Project running in Netbeans 8.0 but not as JAR

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jar

I´m really confused, i´m making a small GUI for UI Automation at Work, works perfectly in Netbeans IDE 8.0, no running problems at all!
But i haven't tried to run the executable jar before and there lies the problem…it isn´t running. The JAR starts, but nothing comes up ???
So i tried du run it via terminal an there is a really long Exception:

[image]

Anyone an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The main cause for a NPE in a jar on the same computer as opposed to a working set of java .class files:

1. Using a `File` instead of `getResource/getResourceAsStream` - a File cannot look in a jar.
2. Using a different letter case, as Windows is case-insensitive, but a jar (zip) not (also not Linux/MacOSX).
3. Class path was more relaxed (+src) and the resource file did not get copied into the jar.

So do a clean build, look into the jar with WinZip/7zip/NetBeans.

Check for suspicious sweeps-under-the-carpet: `catch (Exception e) { }`.

Finally one could look at the error too: the source, and what is done specially with the JList (some component?). The stack trace shows that it is during the layouting of the JList. Is it a simple `JList<String>`?

Comment: I was a bit irritated about the exception and missed the JList… you were right, its about that!  <br/>
The following code was the problem:  <br/><br/>
`Object[] listElems = new File("src/res/testCasses").list();  
this.jListTestfall.setListData(listless);`  <br/><br/>
But why isn´t everything copied to the JAR ? What can i do to make sure everything from project is copied ?

Comment: Aaah, `File.list()` may return null. And in this case, there is no file system `File` src/res/... ; as they are zipped in the jar. On a solution I am less certain.

Comment: i haven´n figured out how to solve it yet…but it is clearly better then having some exceptions. Anyone knows how to access a File zipped in a JAR within a Java class ??? (Absolut Paths aren´t welcomed)